# Change output file for running data stream?

Tags: python, twitter, file-io, output

I created a simple python script that listens to a filtered twitter stream and that writes the data into a simple text file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

# security credentials ommited

searchstr = 'SEARCHSTRING'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        with open('data.txt', 'a') as fp:
            fp.write(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=[searchstr])
```

How can I change the output file every day without stopping the stream of data? I would like to save the file in the format YYYY-MM-DD-data.txt.

My intuition tells me that I need another while loop that continuously checks the time and opens a new file for the output as soon as the date changes. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
'data.txt'
```

with

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d',time.localtime())+'-data.txt'
```

Do not forget to `import time` before using the above code.

`time.localtime()` will get the current local time which will be formatted to YYYY-MM-DD using `time.strftime()`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want the file timestamp in UTC instead of localtime:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-data.txt", time.gmtime(time.time())) 
'2016-06-15-data.txt'
```